# Laravel 5.5 Switching users in the session

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, session, laravel-5

I have made a simple action 'Act as this user' for aplication adminis.
It looks like this:

1. logout current user
2. log in as given user
3. set 'shared_cookie' based on new current user ( \App\Auth\AuthUser::getUserData() gets prepared data based on Auth::user() )

   ```
   public function actAsUser(Request $request, $id)
   {
     Auth::guard()->logout();
     $request->session()->invalidate();
     \Cookie::queue(\Cookie::forget('shared_cookie'));

     $id = \Hashids::decode($id)[0];
     $user = User::find($id);

     Auth::guard()->login($user);
     \Cookie::queue(\Cookie::make('shared_cookie', \App\Auth\AuthUser::getUserData(), config('session.lifetime') , null, config('app.cookie_shared_domain'), false, false));
   }
   ```

It should work, but not quite.
**The result is random!**

'shared_cookie' is always set properly, but in the next request, Auth::user() randomly returns old or new user.

Sometimes it seems, that it depends from the user, but not quite..

Any ideas? Please help!